# Ruby On Rails 2.0.2: Update quantity value of a product after order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Instant-Rails 2.0 and following the Depot example project of Agile Web Development with Rails 3rd edition.

My question is: When a customer makes an order, with the cart and the order form, I need the update the column quantity of products table. 
An example: If I have 10 books (the value "10" is stored in products table with the specific id of the product) and the customer wants 2 books, after the order I want that my project updates the quantity value of available books, decrement it to 8 books.

I tried to add that in `store_controller.rb`, in the add_to_cart method:

```
def add_to_cart
    product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @quantity = Product.find(params[:quantity])
    @cart = find_cart
    @current_item = @cart.add_product(product)
    @removed = Product.remove_q(@quantity)
     respond_to do |format|
         format.js if request.xhr?
         format.html {redirect_to_index}
     end
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    logger.error("Product not found #{params[:id]}")
    redirect_to_index("invalid product!")
  end
```

Where `remove_q` is a method of `product.rb` model:

```
def self.remove_q(quantity)
    @quantity = quantity - 1
  end
```

RoR gives me the error "product not found" in the console when I click in the "add to cart" button. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: Thanks to ipsum for answer. The solution is to decrement the quantities of products after successful order. This is the method `save_order` of `store_controller.rb`:

```
def save_order
@cart = find_cart
@order = Order.new(params[:order])
@order.add_line_items_from_cart(@cart)
@recipient = 'email@notify.com'
@subject = 'Order'
email = Emailer.create_confirm(@order, @recipient, @subject)
email.set_content_type("text/html")
@cliente = sent
if @order.save
    Emailer.deliver(email)
    return if request.xhr?      
    session[:cart] = nil
    redirect_to_index("Thank you")

else
            render :action => 'checkout'
    end
```

end

Please note that `Emailer` is a model for notification via email after successful order, the cart is made from many line_items that are the products customer adds to cart. How can I decrement the quantities of products in cart after successful order? How can I extract products from cart?

There is the model `cart.rb`:

```
class Cart
attr_reader :items

 def initialize
   @items = []
 end

 def add_product(product)
current_item = @items.find {|item| item.product == product}
if current_item
    current_item.increment_quantity

else
       current_item = CartItem.new(product)
   @items << current_item
    end
  current_item
 end

 def total_price
  @items.sum { |item| item.price}
 end

 def total_items
 @items.sum { |item| item.quantity }
 end

 end
```

and the model `line_item.rb`:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :order
 belongs_to :product


 def self.from_cart_item(cart_item)
     li = self.new
     li.product = cart_item.product
     li.quantity = cart_item.quantity
     li.total_price = cart_item.price
     li
 end
end
```

Comment: why are you learning rails 2.0.2 in 2011? If this is your first contact with rails, maybe u should consider rails 3?

Comment: @codinguser I have to do this project on rails 2.0.2 because the teacher explained the example project in this old version. I know, sounds strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to find a product through the quantity.
but "find" expects a primary key

Instead of:

```
@quantity = Product.find(params[:quantity])
```

try this:

```
@quantity = product.quantity
```

UPDATE:

```
def add_to_cart
    product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @cart = find_cart
    @current_item = @cart.add_product(product)
    product.decrement!(:quantity, params[:quantity])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js if request.xhr?
      format.html {redirect_to_index}
    end
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      logger.error("Product not found #{params[:id]}")
      redirect_to_index("invalid product!")
  end
```

Comment: @ipsum  Thank you for your suggestion, I edited that line in the method "add_to_cart" of store_controller.rb. Now I have no errors in the console, but, when I see the list of products, after the confirm of the order, the quantity of the products isn't updated. Maybe I have to rewrite the method "self.remove_q(quantity)" in the model product.rb? Cheers

Comment: @ipsum Thanks, I updated the method, but I have to edit the line:"product.decrement!(:quantity, params[:quantity])" because rails gives me an error on the console of "ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 per 1)) in decrement!".
I edited the line in this way: "product.decrement!(:quantity)" and seems it works! The quantities are updated.

Comment: @ipsum I have solved this problem. Thanks to you. I have another question. If my customer cancels the session and wants to empty the cart, there is in store_controller.rb the method empty_cart:         def empty_cart
                        session[:cart] = nil
                 redirect_to_index
                  end

Comment: @ipsum If I want to solve the reverse problem, I mean, when customer click on "empty cart" button, the quantities need to be restored to original value. I tried to insert an action for this, but I'm doubtful. How can i extract the items from the cart, then restore to original value the quantities of the product that customer before adds to cart and now cancels? Thanks for your answer. Cheers

Comment: you should better decrement the quantity after a successful order.